# Apps on Bluemix and Apps on Softlayer

Tags: security, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I have an application running on Bluemix CF and another (client) application running on Softlayer (but does not matter, it could be on any other external data center).

I need the two applications to communicate together (TCP/HTTPS) with bi-directional communication.

If I install the Secure Gateway client on the Softlayer data center, can I get a bi-directional channel?

Or should I use another service? I have a firewall on Softlayer so maybe I could use a firewall on Bluemix too to filter the entering IP addresses? But did not see any firewall service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to have a look at the Vyatta service on Softlayer

http://www.softlayer.com/network-appliances

You should be able to use this as a secure gateway to limit what can talk to your Softlayer app to only traffic coming from Bluemix (it may take a little trial and error to work out the external range for Bluemix).

If your application on Softlayer is protected with a SSL/TLS connection then you should be able to have both directions protected by suitable level of encryption (Bluemix apps get HTTPS by default)

Comment: from what i understand, the Vyatta service and the Secure Gateway service are offering both a way for my CF (Cloud Foundry) app to access securely to my SL app. BUT is there a service that allow to secure (IP filtering, VPN...) the access from SL app to my CF app (which is playing the backend) here? I was hopping Secure Gateway could do 2-ways but apparently not.

Comment: No BM apps are always going to be public, the best you can do is to access it via https and add authentication to limit access